# Ladda: Spinner not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using [Ladda](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda) to introduce some loading effects on my form buttons. See the [Ladda demo](http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/)

The effect I'm using is `zoom-out`. This works but the spinner doesn't show. Is there something I'm missing?

**My button:**

```
<button type="submit" class="ladda-button" data-style="zoom-out" name="submit">
    <span class="ladda-label">Submit</span>
    <span class="ladda-spinner"></span>
</button>
```

**My JS script** (taken from [here](http://codepen.io/hakimel/pen/gkeha)):

```
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll( '.ladda-button' );

Array.prototype.slice.call( buttons ).forEach( function( button ) {

    var resetTimeout;

    button.addEventListener( 'click', function() {

        if( typeof button.getAttribute( 'data-loading' ) === 'string' ) {
            button.removeAttribute( 'data-loading' );
        }
        else {
            button.setAttribute( 'data-loading', '' );
        }

        clearTimeout( resetTimeout );
        resetTimeout = setTimeout( function() {
            button.removeAttribute( 'data-loading' );           
        }, 3000 );

    }, false );

} );
```

The resources I'm loading are:

- ladda-themeless.min.css
- ladda.min.js
- spin.min.js

Comment: I had never heard of Ladda so I downloaded the demo and changed the css to themeless.min.css. The buttons are now the default browser buttons and the spinner is almost invisible (because it's white). Is the spinner really missing or just not visible like in my case?

Comment: The spinner doesn't show. I cant see the spinner even if I use ladda.min.css which adds a dark background to the button

Comment: when I view the page source and click on the button, no `ladda-progress` div is added to the DOM.

Comment: It looks like your code relies only on the css of Ladda since there is no `Ladda.bind('.ladda-button')`. The spinner is inserted with javascript. What exactly are you trying to do? Have you had a look at Ladda functions like `stop();`?

Comment: any chance you could post a working example? when I use `Ladda.bind('.ladda-button');` instead of my script, everything stopd working

Comment: Hope you've already got it working by now. Anyway I have added an example in my answer. It is actually an extract from the demo.

Comment: i managed to get it working but thanks for your answer. That's the way it's done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have this and it works:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/ladda.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="submit" class="ladda-button" data-style="zoom-out" name="submit">
            <span class="ladda-label">Submit</span>
            <span class="ladda-spinner"></span>
        </button>
        <script src="dist/spin.min.js"></script>
        <script src="dist/ladda.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            Ladda.bind( '.ladda-button', { timeout: 2000 } );
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want to stop the button manually, use one of the functions described in the [documentation](https://github.com/hakimel/Ladda)

Comment: I may be coming too late for the party, but I think my rant is useful. This answer actually really helped me cause it's working. And what's important is to use @Arvin 's answer to include spin.min.js first before ladda.min.js, and as it goes, when you put HTML elements on the page and call the JavaScript upon them, you need to include the script after the elements as they need to load first. Otherwise, the thingy just won't work!

Comment: Be aware, spinner animation does not work with `input` elements, only with `buttons`.

Answer (score 10):

make sure to include `spin.min.js` first and then `ladda.min.js`

Comment: Just a small answer that helped.

Answer (score 5):

I wanted to add this other potential cause of this, which I only just worked out after about an hour of playing around. Note this is not specifically the OP's case, but it is a cause of the spinner not displaying.

The spinner will be invisible if it's the same colour as the button! So if you use `themeless.css` and your button is a standard `btn-default` you will not see the spinner!

Changing the `data-spinner-color` or the colour of your button is a fix in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set any text attribute on the button it will override the spinner

remove     `button.setAttribute( 'data-loading', '' );`